# Is it possible to "lock" dependencies for a Python CLI application on PyPI?

Tags: python, dependency-management, pypi

Let's say I'm developing a Python CLI application, which I plan on distributing to others. The usual way this is done is through the [Python Package Index](https://pypi.org/) and requires me to create a `setup.py` with packaging information.

When I am declaring dependencies for my package, `setup.py` requires me to fill in the `install_requires` parameter of the `setup` function. This is fine but has its limitations, namely *locking* these dependencies.

The problem I want to avoid in my code can be shown through an example: Suppose I declare a dependency such as `requests==2.19.1`, which itself declares `certifi>=2017.4.17` as its own dependency. Fast forward some time later, and `certifi` v2018.3.2 has been released with the whole API rewritten. As `requests` only declares a lower bound to this dependency, it may break with the brand new version of `certifi`, which could then possibly break my code.

How do I lock dependencies for an application that I am publishing to PyPI in order to avoid the aforementioned problem?

Comment: That's not something you as a developer should worry about. That's something for `requests` to worry about, not you, as that's not a direct dependency. There is **always** a possibility that transient dependencies break. Will you worry about Python's dependencies on `sqlite` or the `zlib` library?

Comment: Sure, you can add your own dependencies for all those transitive dependencies and lock everything down to specific versions, but then you are a) making it really hard for anyone to upgrade to new releases with critical security fixes, and b) making it really hard for any other library or tool to co-exist with yours in the same installation target.

Comment: So the best thing to do is to *not worry about that possibility*, and instead trust that the Python ecosystem is reasonably sane and that any project stupid enough to completely break backward compatibilty to that extend is going to have everyone and their aunt fall on them to make sure that that mistake is reverted and fixes ASAP and the developers made an example of to prevent others from being so dumb.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Well that's what major semver versions are for, right? (;P). I mean, the reason this question was asked was because I'm coming from package managers like [Cargo](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo), which locks dependencies for Rust _binary_ packages. As far as coexistence of packages goes, that is _exactly_ what virtualenvs are for; [pipsi](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/pipsi) is what one _should_ be using to install python binary packages.

Comment: Suppose I need to use a library that hasn't been maintained in ~5 years, but declares a wide-open dependency interval that suddenly breaks after a new sub-dependency is released; I don't want to have to deal with adding `sub_package<=X.x` for _my_ package, when locking takes care of this problem. If I don't deal with this problem and let my dependency take care of it, then considering that said dependency is not maintained, my package could stay broken indefinitely.

Comment: Also see https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-package-dependency-blues for a discussion of the topic.

Comment: and look at [Pipenv](https://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for deployment version management.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I really, _really_ wish I could use Pipenv, but alas, there is no way to get the locked dependencies into a `setup.py`. The blog post you linked doesn't really provide a solution (although it does mention similar problems), as users will not really have `pip install -r requirements.txt` available to them when doing `pip install my_cli_app`.